# Какой паттерн отношений мне необходимо использовать?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, laravel5

Есть **Модели** - **Таблицы**:

Status - Statuses ( статусы задачи ) 
Priority - Priorities ( приоритеты )

**Они имеют вид:**

```
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
```

Есть **Модели** - **Таблицы**:
User - Users ( пользователи )

```
------------- ... ---
| id | name |       | # все стандартные поля пользователя
------------- ... ---
```

И главная (на мой взгляд) модель - таблица Task - Tasks:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name | status_id | priority_id | setter_id | responsible_id | ...   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Так же у таблицы есть поля title, body, deadline, factline, create_at, updated_at.

Не моргу понять какой паттерн соотношения между ними. Логика подсказывает, что один ко многим, так как есть таблица Tasks и у неё все уникальные значения статусов, приоритетов, постановщика и ответственного над задачей.
Если так то, в мне необходимо это реализовать на фреймворке **Laravel**. Читаю [документацию](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships#hmt) и не могу понять как это будет работать не с одним уникальным полем а с 4, как это сделано в таблице Task. Объясните пожалуйста.

> UPD Не совсем laravel решение:

```
$tasks = DB::select('SELECT tp.id, tp.title, u.name, u.second_name, us.name AS p_name, us.second_name AS p_second_name, ts.name AS status, tpr.name AS priorities,
                    tp.body, tp.deadline,
                    tp.factline, tp.created_at FROM task_properties AS tp
                    INNER JOIN task_statuses AS ts ON ( ts.id = tp.status )
                    INNER JOIN task_priorities AS tpr ON ( tpr.id = tp.priorities )
                    INNER JOIN users AS u ON ( u.id = tp.setter )
                    INNER JOIN users AS us ON ( us.id = tp.setter )
                    ORDER BY tp.id
                 ');
```

Не получается его реализовать как паттерн в laravel. Подскажите как?

Comment: По моему тут 1 к 1. Не понял где здесь многие? Или вас смущает что тут целых 4 связи 1 к 1?

Comment: @coder675, много задач - один пользователь(создатель либо исполнитель). Так что всё верно.

Comment: А да. Про обратную сторону я как то не подумал.

Comment: @coder675 На чистом `sql` это всё вытаскивается одним запросом. А сдесь мне придётся делать методы в моделях  и в контроллере по одному их вызывать? Как то не совсем удобно. Или что-то не понимаю? Вот например вывод задач списком, Мне ж надо не `id` статуса пользователю показывать.

Comment: И что - в ларке забыли сделать джойны?

Comment: @u_mulder нет не забыли, я пытался, но поле `name` тогда будет значением последней присоеденённой таблицы. И избежать это можно, ели описать отношения, нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такое решение я написал:

```
public function index() {

    $tasks = DB::table('task_properties AS tp')
                    ->select(
                        'tp.id', 'ts.name AS status',
                        'u.name AS setter_name', 'u.second_name AS setter_second_name',
                        'us.name AS responsible_name', 'us.second_name AS responsible_second_name',
                        't_pri.name AS priorities',
                        'tp.title', 'tp.body', 'tp.deadline', 'tp.factline', 'tp.created_at', 'tp.updated_at'
                    )
                    ->join('task_statuses AS ts', 'ts.id', '=', 'tp.status')
                    ->join('task_priorities AS t_pri', 't_pri.id', '=', 'tp.priorities')
                    ->join('users AS u', 'u.id', '=', 'tp.setter')
                    ->join('users AS us', 'us.id', '=', 'tp.responsible')
                    ->get();



    //dump($tasks);

    return view('task.index', compact('tasks'));
}
```